# GTK Label width-chars and halign

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, gobject-introspection

I've got a `Gtk.Label` contained within a `Gtk.Grid` something like as follows:

```
    self.__grid = Gtk.Grid()
    self.__grid.set_row_spacing(2)
    self.__grid.set_column_spacing(5)
    self.__grid.props.margin = 5
#...
    self.clock_label = Gtk.Label("N/A")
    self.clock_label.set_halign(Gtk.Align.START)
    self.__grid.attach(self.clock_label, current_col, current_row, 1, 1)
```

Which works as expected. I encountered an unwanted behavior, though, which meant that as the seconds ticked by, the text of the label being set elsewhere would offset the column (as the clock label is the widest thing in this column) causing all elements to the right of it to shift back and forth as the string itself grew wider (with seconds like 8) or narrower (with seconds like 1).

To solve this, I added a line to the setup code for this label

```
    self.clock_label.set_width_chars(8)
```

And voila, it worked. However, it *insists* on centering the text when I do that, irrespective of the presence or absence of the `set_halign()`.

I would like very much to have a label whose text starts on the left-hand border of its cell, but whose width is also padded such that changes in string length are of no concern.

Any help is appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994255/) after SO gave it to me in the Related column. Turns out that `xalign` (with a parameter of 0.0) butts the label up against the left boundary just as I wanted. Hooray.

Though, I don't see anywhere that `halign` is actually depreciated. [Here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-halign) or [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_halign). Is it not, then? This is a touch confusing.

Comment: `halign` is common to all widgets and affects the **widget** alignment. `xalign` is specific to `GtkLabel` and affects the **text** alignment. The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#GtkLabel--xalign) says the same thing (although IMO in a quite cryptical form).